# generating flat files for different sql files in single SSIS package

Tags: ssis-2012, flat-file, foreach-loop-container, dataflowtask

I have a folder which contains different SQL files. Now in the SSIS package, in foreach loop, I'm reading the query stored in each sql files (with script task) and later executing the query in the Execute script task and thus getting a resultset in a variable.

Now I want to generate flat files corresponding to each of these resultset variable.

Is this procedure possible (I have tried using dataflowtask but it is not using variable as a source) or should I proceed with a different approach?

Comment: Is it your first package or did you try any other method??

Comment: i tried using dataflowtask in foreach loop but i dont think for each iteration we can change the command text to different query...

Comment: you shuld try a dynamic query in that case.. Need more clarity on your question

Comment: I have different query files which are not related to each other. Each query is returning data and i need to generate flat files for each using package.

Comment: how many files specifically?

Comment: around 50 SQL files.

Comment: do u want all sql files to get combined? does they use same table schema?

Comment: No, all SQL files are for different purpose..they basically use same db but all files are independent of each other. I require different flat files for different SQL files.

Comment: why SSIS for this? any specific reason?

Comment: Data extraction and loading. Initially flat files was generated one by one by directly running the query in ssms and saving the resultset into CSV file now this process needs to be automated.

Comment: Can it be done through ssis?

Comment: since it is of 50 queries. need a lot of analysis before giving a scalable solution .. let me know. what best I can help you out

Answer (score 0):

`OLE DB Source` has an option under `Data access mode` called `SQL command from variable`. I think this is the one you are looking for.

You can use parameterized query as below screenshot:
[image]

While suggested solution:
[image]

Comment: This option is used for parameterized query i.e select query part is fixed and we are filtering the query through parameters in each iteration eg select * from order where year > @variable.  In my case, each query has different table schema so cant be parameterized.

Comment: i tried this but its not working when in forloop iteration. In my case, each query returns different columns so it fails in the second iteration (in datafowtask) as proper column mapping does not occur with the oledb datasource columns